# Is there any neural network model for regression vector from vector?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I am trying to find a neural network model for regression with vector. Specifically, I have several different curves. Each curve generated by vector **x** and vector **y**. The **x** contains 40 elements and **y** contains 40 elements. Also, each curve has a specific label. For example, I have many curves, for one curve, **x** is the number of costumers like [1, 3, 6,..., 50], **y** is the corresponding income of this shop by selling product **a**, like [100, 120, 140, ...200](when there is 1 costumer, income is 100). For another curve, **x** is the number of costumers again like [1, 5, 7, 12,...,70], **y** is the corresponding income by selling product **b**,  like[120, 130, 150, ..., 300]. And I also have curves for product **c**, **d**, **e**....

In this example, if I am supposing there is a relationship between curve **a**, **b**, **c**... And it is possible to use this relationship to predict curve **c** through learning **a**, **b**, **d** and other curves. What type of neural network or machine learning algorithm should I use? Basically, I think this problem is using a vector to fit a vector. In other words, the input would be vector **x** and the product label **c**, the output should be the vector **y**.

My idea is the vector can often be seen as time-series data, so maybe I can use RNN, or LSTM. The problem is the **x** is not the previous part of **y**, so I'm not sure if I can take it as a time series data.

Also, the curve highly depends on the product label in the example. How to feed this label into the neural network is a problem. Even for the same vector **x**, the predicted curves **y** should be different with different labels.

Comment: Can you show us a super simplified example, as your description is quite hard to follow. It sounds like you have 41 features (40 values in a 'vector' and 1 'label') and 40 targets. This is a normal multivariate regression, and you could use anything from linear regressions right the way through to RNNs?

Comment: Yes, basically I am using 41 features to regression 40 targets. Do you think RNN can be used? Or I can just go with a simple ANN? I am supposing there is some relationship similar to time-series data. For example, if the **x** changes from 7 to 20, **y** should also have a big jump.